# Why does Vec<T>::split_at_mut borrow the vector for the rest of the scope?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

`Vec<T>` has two methods:

```
fn push(&mut self, value: T)
fn split_at_mut(&mut self, mid: usize) -> (&mut [T], &mut [T])
```

They both take a mutable reference to the vector. But the scope of the borrow seems to be different, e.g:

```
fn works() {
    let mut nums: Vec<i64> = vec![1,2,3,4];
    nums.push(5);
    println!("{}", nums.len());
}

fn doesnt_work() {
    let mut nums: Vec<i64> = vec![1,2,3,4];
    let (l,r) = nums.split_at_mut(2);
    println!("{}", nums.len());
}

fn also_works() {
    let mut nums: Vec<i64> = vec![1,2,3,4];
    let _ = nums.split_at_mut(2);
    println!("{}", nums.len());
}
```

The `doesnt_work` function doesn't compile, saying there is already a mutable borrow on `nums` and that it ends and the end of the function. The problem goes away if I ignore the values returned from `split_at_mut`.

Comment: Note that this is the same underlying question as http://stackoverflow.com/q/32761524/155423.

Comment: The code posted above will compile just fine in modern rust, btw.

Answer (score 8):

The borrowing of `nums` in `doesnt_work` will last as long as the variables `l` and `r` exist because the values in the vector (and the vector itself) have literally been borrowed and are now accessible only through `l` and `r`.

You can see this effect by putting the `let` for `l` and `r` in a scope which ends so the borrow also ends. For example this code works fine but if you try to move the `println!` inside the scope (inside the curly brackets) then it will fail:

```
fn works() {
    let mut nums = vec![1,2,3,4];

    {
        let (l, r) = nums.split_at_mut(2);
        //println!("{}", nums.len()); //println! will fail here
    }

    println!("{}", nums.len());
}
```

In your `also_works` example you don't do anything with the result so the borrow is lost immediately. Basically the compiler can see that there is no way you can access the vector through the result of the method so you're free to access them through the original vector.

Comment: This comment made a click in my brain of how ownership really works in Rust. Thankss!!!

Answer (score 3):

Let me answer my own question, since what I was really missing were lifetimes. This code compiles:

```
fn maybe_use<'a, 'b>(v1: &'a mut Vec<i64>, v2: &'b mut Vec<i64>) -> &'a mut Vec<i64> {
    v1
}

fn main() {
    let mut nums1: Vec<i64> = vec![1,2,3,4];
    let mut nums2: Vec<i64> = vec![1,2,3,4];

    let ret = maybe_use(&mut nums1, &mut nums2);

    println!("{}", nums2.len());
}
```

Because the return type of maybe_use makes it clear the reference comes from the first argument. If we change `v2` to use `'a` lifetime, `main` stops compiling because both vectors passed to `maybe_use` are considered borrowed. If we omit the lifetime altogether, compiler emits this error:

> this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but the
>   signature does not say whether it is borrowed from `v1` or `v2`

So what surprised me initially (how does the compiler know `split_at_mut` returns pointers to the vector?) boils down to the references having the same lifetime.

Comment: You got it, congratulations!