# Why does HashMap::get_mut() take ownership of the map for the rest of the scope?

Tags: rust

I have the following code that inserts some values into a HashMap and then gets them back out:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn things() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(5, "thing");
    map.insert(4, "world");
    map.insert(1, "hello");
    let mut thing = map.remove(&5);
    let mut world = map.get_mut(&4);
    let mut hello = map.get_mut(&1);
}
```

Attempting to compile this code gives the following error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `map` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:10:21
   |
9  |     let mut world = map.get_mut(&4);
   |                     --- first mutable borrow occurs here
10 |     let mut hello = map.get_mut(&1);
   |                     ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
11 | }
   | - first borrow ends here
```

After perusing the API docs for both the `remove()` and [`get_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_mut) methods (fortunately they are pretty close to each other!) there is nothing that stands out to me from the method signatures why the `remove()` method does not mutably borrow the map for the rest of the current scope while the `get_mut()` method does.

The other piece of data that I have that also mystifies me is that this code compiles:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn things() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(5, "thing");
    map.insert(4, "world");
    map.insert(1, "hello");
    let mut thing = map.remove(&5);
    map.get_mut(&4);
    let mut hello = map.get_mut(&1);
}
```

Not storing the result of the first call to `get_mut()` doesn't cause the map to be mutably borrowed for the rest of the scope?  How could I have known this from looking at the documentation?  Am I missing something else?

Comment: Note that this is the same underlying question as http://stackoverflow.com/q/32761370/155423.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This error is a limitation of the implementation of the borrow checker before [*non-lexical lifetimes*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251487/what-are-non-lexical-lifetimes). With those enabled, the original code will work as-is:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn things() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(5, "thing");
    map.insert(4, "world");
    map.insert(1, "hello");
    let mut thing = map.remove(&5);
    let mut world = map.get_mut(&4);
    let mut hello = map.get_mut(&1);
}

fn main() {}
```

This is because the compiler is smarter and can see that you aren't using `world` anymore by the time you get to `map.get_mut(&1)`, so it doesn't need to have a valid reference anymore.

You can get equivalent code in previous versions of Rust by adding an explicit scope:

```
let mut thing = map.remove(&5);
{
    let mut world = map.get_mut(&4);
}
let mut hello = map.get_mut(&1);
```

---

> Why does `HashMap::get_mut()` take ownership of the map

It absolutely does **not** do that. *Ownership* is a precise term in Rust code. Note that the error message specifically says

> previous borrow of `map` occurs here

A *borrow* is not ownership. If I borrow your car, I don't own your car.

Your real question is "why does it borrow it for the rest of the scope". Let's look at the signature:

```
fn get_mut<Q: ?Sized>(&mut self, k: &Q) -> Option<&mut V> 
where
    K: Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Hash + Eq,
```

In words, this could be read as

> Given a mutable reference to a `HashMap` (`&mut self`) and something that can be used to find the key (`K: Borrow<Q>, Q: Hash + Eq`), return a mutable reference to the value if one matches (`Option<&mut V>`)

However, that returned mutable reference will be changing *something* in the `HashMap`, that's why it's a mutable reference at all. You are only allowed to have multiple immutable borrows OR one mutable borrow at a time. This prevents writing code that causes inconsistencies and safety issues.

Let's look at `remove`:

```
fn remove<Q: ?Sized>(&mut self, k: &Q) -> Option<V> 
where
    K: Borrow<Q>, 
    Q: Hash + Eq,
```

This returns an *owned* value, not a reference into the `HashMap`. Once the method is done, the borrow of the map is over.

Comment: I think I have it.  When you have a method on struct that mutably borrows `self` and that method returns a mutable reference, the only valid assumption is that mutable reference is to some field on that struct, which transitively keeps the borrow on the struct alive.  Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: It's worth noting lifetimes play a part here, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32768690/81896.

Comment: @MichałBendowski absolutely. It's just in this case, *lifetime elision* ties the lifetimes of `self` and the return value together, so you don't have to write it out explicitly.